# Angular(v4.0.0)でページ遷移する際、スクロール位置が保持される。

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular2, angular4

Angular（v4.0.0）でページ遷移する際に、遷移前のページのスクロール位置が遷移後のページに保持されたまま遷移してしまいます。
遷移方法は以下のようにrouterLinkを用いています。

```
<a routerLink="/page2"></a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

これは、Angular（v4.0.0）の仕様なのでしょうか？
また、仕様であれば、この機能をoffにすることはできるのでしょうか？

ご存知のかたは、教えていただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/80822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

現時点では「仕様」のようで、
Angularとしての機能としてOffにするような方法はないように思えます。

以下Angular Issueでも議論されておりますが、設定的な方法ではなく、処理を入れてしまう対処案しか出ていません。
[Changing route doesn't scroll to top in the new page #7791](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7791)

とりあえずは私も上記ページにある内のひとつの方法である
以下をngOnInitに入れることによって対処しています(↑のIssue#7791内のtrickでは突入された側のRouterではなく去り側のRouterでsetしています。)

```
this.renderer.setElementProperty(document.body, "scrollTop", 0);
```

私見入りますが、あまり良い「仕様」とは言えないのでAngularTeamにconfig方法をRequestしたいところです。(とりあえず上記#7791にVoteしました。)